# Error Message in Active MQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am sending xml messages over the activemq queue using Camel route. Message is reaching to the queue but its not able to read it. Not sure if it is a apache camel issue or Active MQ issue.
My camel route is

```
<route>
            <from uri="seda:elixirBatchQueue" />
            <inOnly uri="activemq:queue:TESTQUEUE"/>
        </route>
```

Error Message in the queue is

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from bytes. Reason: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with ActiveMQ as it was not able to understand the message format. When I converted it to String, Queue was able to recognize message as a DOM4J document.

Comment: @ClausIbsen As per StackOverFlow policy, I can only do it after 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me.

```
producer.Send(objectMessage.Body);
```

The library I used -->> `Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ`